# Table with granulated columns not showing "Null" for missing value (Google Data Studio)

Tags: null, missing-data, looker-studio, granularity

I created a table in Google Data Studio using Google Sheets as the Data Set:

[image: Screenshot of the table]

I changed the granularity of the date column to "Year month" to group the data in months. As you can see July 2020 is missing from the table. My source data doesn't have any values matching a date in July and that's why it is missing. But I want July 2020 to show up in the table with a "null" or "0" or "no data". I chose the setting the for "missing data" show "null" and yet its not showing up.

Added data set: [Google sheet dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay0Fo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of going about it are:

### 1) Add data in the Data Set

The feature is currently not implemented in Google Data Studio [Tables](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044), thus one approach would be to add the Date (July 2020) at the [Data Set](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6314481) (Google Sheet).

**Update**: Added a [New Page to the Report](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/0bc159c4-2cf8-4c24-a214-09369b2834d9/page/KA2gB/edit) as well as an image to demonstrate, where the highlighted rows in Orange represent the added Date, `July 2020` (Note that `NULL`, `0` or the required value could be used as a metric):

[image]

### 2) Time Series Chart

Alternatively, a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) chart could be created, which would display the month of July as 0 (missing data is set to **Line to Zero** by default).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/0bc159c4-2cf8-4c24-a214-09369b2834d9) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]